# Titanium:Giving error and Nothing getting in when trying to access json data from remote server

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

Hi I am new in Titanium mobile app I am trying to get data from remote server but failed. I am using Titanium Studio, build: 3.2.1.201402041146.

This is my index.xml file

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup id="mainTabGroup">
        <!-- On click event execute getTodoList -->
        <Tab id="tab1" onClick="getTodoList">
            <Window id="readWin">
                <TableView id="tableView"/>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
        <Tab id="tab2">
            <Window id="insertWin">
                <View id="mainView">
                    <TextField id="inserTxtF"/>
                    <Button id="insertBtn" onClick="insertData" />
                </View>
            </Window>
        </Tab>
    </TabGroup>
  </Alloy>
```

///// And this is my index.js file code////

```
//Array to store the data from the todo list

 var dataArray = [];

//We execute the function to show the data for the first view

    getTodoList();


function getTodoList () {

    var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onerror: function(e){
            Ti.API.debug(e.error);
            alert('There was an error during the conexion');
        },
        timeout:1000,
    });

    //Here you have to change it for your local ip

    sendit.open('GET', 'http://attarisoft.com/read_todo_list.php');  
    sendit.send(); 
    //Function to be called upon a successful response
    sendit.onload = function(){
        var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        var json = json.todo;
        //if the database is empty show an alert
        if(json.length == 0){
            $.tableView.headerTitle = "The database row is empty";
        }

        //Emptying the data to refresh the view
        dataArray = [];

        //Insert the JSON data to the table view
        for( var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
            var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                title: json[i].todo,
                hasChild : true,
            });     
            dataArray.push(row);                
        };

        $.tableView.setData(dataArray);

     };
  }
```

//// this is giving alert message There was an error during the conexion and nothing display in table view please help

Comment: I can see that in http://www.attarisoft.com/read_todo_list.php the JSON is beeing retrieved and showed in the website, inside index.js try to use `Ti.API.info(JSON.stringify(this.responseText))` (this is like console.log) inside `sendit.onload = function()` also there is an alert message in the post method, try to use cURL to post directly to the database it should be something like `curl -X POST -d @filename http://hostname/resource` please let me know if this help

Comment: @ thanks for your reply but my problem not solved. So what can be the reason.Because so many people facing this problem to view data in listing to get from JSON.

Comment: have you try to encapsulate the problem, something to start is to check the connection to your server, `sendit.open('GET', 'http://attarisoft.com/read_todo_list.php');` I am not sure if the problem is this line of code because this leads directly to onerror property of the sendit object, also are you testing this in the emulator? or in a real device? both of them can show log errors, please let me see the log of the application

Comment: I am testing it In Mobile Web Preview in browser. And also I gave simple jsot.tx file like http://attarisoft.com/json.txt but same problem. can u write an example code with curl _x Post -d.

Comment: One thing I am using Win 7 x32 machine. So this is ok?

Comment: Also suggest that is there any setting enable in browser to createHTTPClient.

Comment: @Mario bug pointed out that403 http://www.attarisoft.com/json.txt 403 (Forbidden).
http://attarisoft.com/json.txt No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8020' is therefore not allowed access.
So what will be solution

Comment: I am also giving sendit.open('GET', 'http://attarisoft.com/json.txt'); 
      sendit.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
     sendit.send(); but giving error
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8020' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Hello @Attarisoft sorry for the late response I have face this problem before 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and the backend guys fix that problem in the server side also there are some headers you can change in your titanium code: please refer to this links so you can change your code: [link]http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/136724/createhttpclient-gives-a-cant-reach-host-error [link]http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/156604/mobile-web-312-cross-domain-ws-post-request-header-field-x-titanium-id-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-headers

Comment: @Mario I change it but first alert show success and then twice show error and also I used  sendit.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://attarisoft.com");
 
 sendit.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 
 sendit.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 
 
 sendit.send();
but not any response. I am pulling my hair in this problem but ....

Comment: yeah this header problems and Access-Control-Allow-Origin are a tough error I had to raise a JIRA ticket so the Appcelertor guys help me on the same problem, but the problem is in the server side, the backend guys change a line of code in the config file of the server. Because if you try and test the same code in the android or iOS version this does not happen

Comment: Have you had enabled CORS in your server? http://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0):

index.js

```
  function getTodoList(){
    var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({

        onload : function(e){
          var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
          Ti.API.info(json);//Check your data to return

          var json = json.todo;
          //if the database is empty show an alert
          if(json.length == 0){
              $.tableView.headerTitle = "The database row is empty";
          }

          //Emptying the data to refresh the view
          dataArray = [];

          //Insert the JSON data to the table view
          for( var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
              var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                  title: json[i].todo,
                  hasChild : true,
              });     
              dataArray.push(row);                
          };

          $.tableView.setData(dataArray);

        },
        onerror: function(e){
            Ti.API.info(e.error);
            alert('There was an error during the conexion');
        },
        timeout:5000, 
});

//Here you have to change it for your local ip

sendit.open('GET', 'http://attarisoft.com/read_todo_list.php');  
sendit.send();
}
$.mainTabGroup.open();
```

index.xml

```
<Alloy>
<TabGroup id="mainTabGroup">
    <!-- On click event execute getTodoList -->
    <Tab id="tab1"  title="Main" onFocus="getTodoList">
        <Window id="readWin">
            <TableView id="tableView"/>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
    <Tab id="tab2" title="Second">
        <Window id="insertWin">
            <View id="mainView">
                <TextField id="inserTxtF"/>
                <Button id="insertBtn" />
            </View>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</TabGroup>
```

The problem was tab event. OnClick --> OnFocus for Tab

Comment: Thanks but this is not a solution. Same problem. Actually I am also calling this function at load event and also at click event. but problem same.

Comment: Tab has not click event. You should use onFocus event for loading.

Comment: I used focus event but same problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you stepped across some problems here:

- First, in your code, you are sending the request before setting the callback function. Though this should work, not sure if it'll behave exactly like you want.
- I've had better success with these requests by explicitly setting error and timeouts (instead of  assigning these values upon creation).

That being said, try this code out:

```
function getTodoList () {

var sendit = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

//Here you have to change it for your local ip

sendit.open('GET', 'http://attarisoft.com/read_todo_list.php');  
//Function to be called upon a successful response
sendit.onload = function(){
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var json = json.todo;
    //if the database is empty show an alert
    if(json.length == 0){
        $.tableView.headerTitle = "The database row is empty";
    }

    //Emptying the data to refresh the view
    dataArray = [];

    //Insert the JSON data to the table view
    for( var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: json[i].todo,
            hasChild : true,
        });     
        dataArray.push(row);                
    };

    $.tableView.setData(dataArray);

 };
 sendit.onerror = function(){
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('There was an error during the conexion');
 };
 sendit.setTimeout(10000); // 10 sec for timeout
 sendit.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
 sendit.send();
 }
```

One last advice, it's better create a separate module to handle this requests (assuming you'll do that more than once).
If this still doesn't fix you problem, please post back your new errors.
Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks @ LucasA but this is giving alert message There was an error during the conexion.

Comment: One thing I am using Win 7 x32 machine. So this is ok?

Comment: I am also giving sendit.open('GET', 'http://attarisoft.com/json.txt'); 
      sendit.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); 
     sendit.send(); but giving error
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8020' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I don't think your OS version is the problem. To which platforms are you developing? Are you behind any firewalls? If you debug you code, can you successfully create an http connection and only crash during send?

Answer (score 0):

fixed as follow

```
            var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
    client.open("GET", "http://www.domainname.com/read_todo_list.php", true);
    client.send();
    client.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if (client.readyState==4 && client.status==200)
        {
        //console.log(JSON.parse(client.response));
        //json = JSON.stringify(client.response);
        var get=JSON.parse(client.response);
        console.log(get['todo']);
        for( var i=0; i < get['todo'].length; i++){

        var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
            title: get['todo'][i].todo,
            hasChild : true,
            });     
            dataArray.push(row);                
        }

        $.tableView.setData(dataArray);

        }




    };
```